# Why is localhost returning "502 Bad Gateway"?

Tags: localhost, mamp

When I googled this issue, I noticed this is a common issue with nginx. But I never used nginx in my machine. I work with MAMP and occasionally with Python Bottle.

Now whether my MAMP/Python server is on or not, I always get "502 Bad Gateway" whenever the address bar URL contains the word "**localhost**". Hence, I am having to use "**127.0.0.1**" in the meanwhile.

I am really confused as I have no idea which particular event has caused this issue to start happening in my [Mac OS X v10.7.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion).

Comment: Restart the Nginx - it works for me most of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this issue myself with MAMP - visiting `localhost:8888/anything` gave me a 502, but `127.0.0.1` worked fine.

I discovered that it was my VPN ([Hotspot Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_Shield) in this case) causing the issue (although I'm not sure why). I disconnected from the VPN and `localhost` works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/nginx/site-available/default` file and make sure that php7.1-fpm.sock is the proper PHP version you installed.

On line:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users, you can enter the following in the terminal:

```
dscacheutil -flushcach
```